# When we state hypothesis does it mean null hypothesis or alternative hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics

In one of assignments in a study programme I got this statement:

> **Hypothesis**: University towns have their mean housing prices less effected by recessions. Run a t-test to compare the ratio of the mean
>   price of houses in university towns the quarter before the recession
>   starts compared to the recession bottom.

Here I am confused The term **Hypothesis** whether it referes to **Alternate** Hypothesis or **Null** Hypothesis.

Comment: It's neither: this is a "scientific" or "substantive" hypothesis.

Comment: With about 95% certainty, the first sentence specifies the alternative hypothesis that you should try to investigate using the method outlined afterwards. It would be more clear to start with "A researcher postulates that university towns.... by recession...."

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the alternative hypothesis.

When we do hypothesis testing, we hold out that our hypothesis, in this case that university towns (group 1) have their mean housing prices less effected by recessions than non-university towns (group 2), as the alternative and we create a second hypothesis called the null hypothesis, which in this case would be that there is no difference between the two groups. We then examine the groups to determine whether this null hypothesis is true or not.